How to register a custom JsonValueReaderWriter implementation in Entity Framework Core?
I have a database with JSON columns in it, where one of the types within the JSON requires some special handling. I am currently developing a DbContext for it with Entity Framework Core 8, and have written a class derived from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Json.JsonValueReaderWriter<> to handle the special casing for this particular type of object (which is somewhat deep in the JSON documents being stored in each row of this particular table). What I cannot determine is how do I get EF Core to use my particular reader/writer for the objects that need it.
In my context's OnModelCreating() method, I've defined the entity type for the table containing the JSON documents, with the JSON column set up similar to this:
entity.OwnsMany(
    e => e.Articles,
    articleBuilder =>
    {
        articleBuilder.ToJson();
        articleBuilder.WithOwner(a => a.Document);
        articleBuilder.OwnsMany(
            a => a.Subarticles,
            subBuilder =>
            {
                subBuilder.WithOwner(s => s.Article);
                subBuilder.OwnsMany(s => s.Sections);
            });
    });

It's the objects in the Sections collections that require the special handling.
I have a class that handles serialization and deserialization between Section objects and JSON, and I've looked for how I can configure the DbContext to use it, but there doesn't seem to be any relevant methods or extension methods usable from OnModelCreating() or ConfigureConventions() (or any builders accessible through either).

Related: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27779
